# Java: Using Command line arguments to process the names of files

Tags: java, command-line, textinput

I'm a writing a program that will determine the number of lines, characters, and average word length for a text file. For the program, the specifications say that the file or files will be entered as a command line argument and that we should make a TestStatistic object for each file entered. I don't understand how to write the code for making the TestStatistic objects if the user enters more than one file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most basic way to process command line arguments is:

```
public class TestProgram
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        for (String s : args)
        {
            // do something with each arg
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The preferable way is to use something that manages the command line arguments for you. I suggest [JSAP: The Java Simple Argument Parser](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/).

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) use System.exit to exist. Just let the main method return.

Comment: explict is better than implict especially for beginners!

Comment: Well it doesn't get any more explicit than assembly, so maybe they should start there? I disagree, higher abstraction is better for beginners. Obviously you agree to some degree since you're recommending the for-each construct instead of the more explicit standard for loop.

Comment: I recommend an explicit System.exit(0); that would be counter to an explicit System.exit(2); if there were something wrong with the arguments, and I highly recommend using JSAP instead of doing all this parsing of the array manually.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you simply need to iterate through your command line args and produce a TestStatistic object for each.

e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   for (String arg : args) {
      TestStatistic ts = new TestStatistic(arg); // assuming 'arg' is the name of a file
   }
   // etc...
```

Comment: your code looks weird, the scope of ts is wrong. It would be clearer if you have a collection or something like that. That seems a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an expansion on other general answers, flushed out a bit further.

```
public class TextFileProcessor
{
    private List testStatisticObjects = new ArrayList();

    private void addFile(String fileName)
    {
        testStatisticObjects.add(new TestStatistic(fileName));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TextFileProcessor processor = new TextFileProcessor();
        for (String commandLineArgument : args)
        {
            //consider validating commandLineArgument here
            processor.addFile(commandLineArgument);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use something like [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) to process command line.

Comment: this is a terrible suggestion, Commons CLI is a crusty crappy library that isn't even maintained and has horrible semantics.